# Currying merge_with in python toolz

Tags: python, currying, toolz

I would like to be able to curry `merge_with`:

`merge_with` works as I expect

```
>>> from cytoolz import curry, merge_with
>>> d1 = {"a" : 1, "b" : 2}
>>> d2 = {"a" : 2, "b" : 3}
>>> merge_with(sum, d1, d2)
{'a': 3, 'b': 5}
```

On a simple function, `curry` works as I expect:

```
>>> def f(a, b):
...     return a * b
... 
>>> curry(f)(2)(3)
6
```

But I'm not able to "manually" make a curried version of `merge_with`:

```
>>> curry(merge_with)(sum)(d1, d2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
>>> curry(merge_with)(sum)(d1)(d2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
```

The pre-curried version works:

```
>>> from cytoolz.curried import merge_with as cmerge
>>> cmerge(sum)(d1, d2)
{'a': 3, 'b': 5}
```

Where is my mistake?

Comment: Here is me again finding a question I posted earlier while having the same question again...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because `merge_with` takes `dicts` as positional arguments:

```
merge_with(func, *dicts, **kwargs)
```

so `f` is the only obligatory argument, and for empty `*args` you get an empty dictionary:

```
>>> curry(merge_with)(sum)  # same as merge_with(sum)
{}
```

so:

```
curry(f)(2)(3)
```

is equivalent to

```
>>> {}(2)(3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
```

You'll have to explicit and define helper

```
def merge_with_(f):
    def _(*dicts, **kwargs):
        return merge_with(f, *dicts, **kwargs)
    return _
```

which can be used as you want:

```
>>> merge_with_(sum)(d1, d2)
{'a': 3, 'b': 5}
```

or:

```
def merge_with_(f, d1, d2, *args, **kwargs):
    return merge_with(f, d1, d2, *args, **kwargs)
```

which can both

```
>>> curry(merge_with_)(sum)(d1, d2)
{'a': 3, 'b': 5}
```

and:

```
>>> curry(merge_with_)(sum)(d1)(d2)
{'a': 3, 'b': 5}
```